# Convert YouTube link into an embed link

Tags: python, regex, flask

I am using Python and Flask, and I have some YouTube URLs I need to convert to their embed versions. For example, this:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3iFhLdWjqc`

has to be converted into this:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/X3iFhLdWjqc`

Should I use Regexp, or is there a Flask method to convert the URLs?

Comment: you could achieve it with regex or with [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) but I don't think Flask knows how to do it

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't knew Python could do that. Really thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your URLs are just strings, you don't need regexes or special Flask functions to do it.
This code will replace all YouTube URLs with the embedded versions, based off of how you said it should be handled:

```
url = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=TESTURLNOTTOBEUSED"
url = url.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
```

All you have to do is replace `url` with whatever variable you store the URL in.
To do this for a list, use:

```
new_url_list = list()
for address in old_url_list:
    new_address = address.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
    new_url_list.append(new_address)

old_url_list = new_url_list
```

where `old_url_list` is the list which your URLs are included in.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. It wasn't a string but I had to convert it into one.

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of youtube links:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx

or

http://youtu.be/xxxxxxxxxxx

Use this function it will work with the 2 kinds of youtube links.

```
import re
def embed_url(video_url):
        regex = r"(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)"

        return re.sub(regex, r"https://www.youtube.com/embed/\1",video_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re

videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3iFhLdWjqc" 
embedUrl = re.sub(r"(?ism).*?=(.*?)$", r"https://www.youtube.com/embed/\1", videoUrl )
print (embedUrl)
```

---

Output:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/X3iFhLdWjqc
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/4bfc4f383f)

Comment: Multiple parameters in the URL could be an issue.

Comment: Agree, but OP didn't mention that.